# Why when I send XML to PHP are the nodes lowercase, but when I parse them in PHP they are uppercase?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

This is a follow up question to this answer:

[How do I parse XML from PHP that was sent to the server as text/xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948610/how-do-i-parse-xml-from-php-that-was-sent-to-the-server-as-text-xml)

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var xmlDoc = jQuery.createXMLDocument( "<items></items>" );
jQuery( "items", xmlDoc ).append( jQuery( "<item>My item!</item>" ) );
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    data: xmlDoc,
    success: function( data ) {
        alert( data );
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$xml_text = file_get_contents("php://input");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_text);
echo $xml->ITEM;
```

In order for this to work I have to use $xml->ITEM. If I use $xml->item it will not work. I was wondering why when the item node gets appended it is lowercase, but when I retrieve it, it now has to be uppercase? I would like it to be lowercase in my PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using http://plugins.jquery.com/project/createXMLDocument ? And with what browsers did you test it?

Comment: Yes, I am. Just Firefox for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP script receives <items><ITEM>My item!</ITEM></items> as input. Try

```
<?php
$xml_text = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents('test.log.txt', $xml_text);
```

if you think this isn't so.

xmlDoc is an xml document, but the result of jQuery( "<item>My item!</item>" ) isn't.
Along the way jQuery uses .nodeName which behaves like .tagName for elements.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName says:

> In XML (and XML-based languages such as XHTML), tagName preserves case. In HTML, tagName **returns the element name in the canonical uppercase form**. The value of tagName is the same as that of nodeName.

Comment: So I guess the question still remains, how I can get my PHP to do a case insensitive search on the ITEM node itself? I've been searching for an XPath solution or a SimpleXML solution and can't find one.

Comment: You don't need to do a case insensitive search. It will always be uppercase. If you are searching an arbitrary node name, just cast it to uppercase using strtoupper().