# Case insensitivity in selectors?

Tags: jquery, xml, case

I am trying to use jQuery for XML processing. One of the problem that I am stuck with jQuery is it is case insensitive in processing tags and attribute.

For e.g., consider the following code:

```
$("<div><Book ISBN='1234'>Some title</Book></div>").html()
```

the output we get is:

```
<book isbn="1234">Some title</book>
```

whereas the output i am looking for is:

```
<Book ISBN="1234">Some title</Book>
```

Any possibility? (Note that "B" is capital letter, and the whole attribute name "ISBN" is also in capital case, whereas the jQuery html output is completely lower case) Please help.

Comment: Why do you need the cases to be preserved?  Are you having trouble parsing/traversing the XML?  `$xml.find('Book')` and `$xml.find('book')` are identical in jQuery, as are `$xml.attr('ISBN')` and `$xml.attr('isbn')`.

Comment: exactly what i was trying at the moment... .html works as expected lowering the case but .find is working with either case. therefor could be used to find Book but will also return book. !

Comment: Greetings and signatures are discouraged in SO questions/answers. Cheers

Comment: jQuery isn't good with XML processing. Just so you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html, in HTML 
element names are case-insensitive, but in XML they are case- 
sensitive. The same is true for attribute names.

So, the HTML output you are getting is correct. To my knowledge, 
jQuery core can't create an HTML document, where case sensitivity matters for element and attribute names.

EDIT: See below. I had originally said jQuery can't create an XML document where case sensitivity matters. Clearly, it can. But it can't preserve the case if you're injecting into HTML. For a solution, see: [jQuery converting XML tags to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351527/jquery-converting-xml-tags-to-uppercase/4351599#4351599)

Comment: *"To my knowledge, jQuery core can't create an XML document"* Sure it can: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ :-)

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder. I never said it couldn't create an XML document. I said jQuery can't create an XML document <em>where case sensitivity matters for element and attribute names.</em> Did you read the question?

Comment: `@two:` I was mostly joking about an over-generalization, but: Again: Sure it can: http://jsbin.com/ibixey Note how the `test` and `TEST` elements are **not** the same. @Lil'Monkey is right that it's much more about the `html` method than it is about jQuery's ability to work with XML correctly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: http://jsbin.com/upiniy/2 - I also never said jQuery can't work with XML correctly (although I'm not sure I agree, but let's save that for another time). Read the question again, and my answer. Your test just proves that jQuery can select XML nodes by case, not that it can create case-sensitive XML documents. Suggest reading: http://ejohn.org/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/

Comment: `@two:` Curiously enough, I have read that post from Resig just recently. You said jQuery couldn't create XML document with case sensitivity. It can, and that's what the link demonstrates. What it can't do, and for good reason, is inject XML nodes **into an HTML document** and reliably preserve the case of the tagnames.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - the harsh light of day hits, and I finally concede you your point. I think my answer now reflects what I meant to say, but maybe I was just plain wrong from the get-go. Thanks!

Comment: I probably just wasn't quite being clear. :-) +1 and we should probably clean up these comments.

Answer (score 1):

the problem would be the .html() ... html in itself should be lowercase so jquery jsut return the "Valid" html format. if u need to parse xml i am sure theres librairy to do it that will keep the Case of your Xml.

personally i would try parsexml or any of the library you could find with a quick search

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the XML I was pulling from another site output the actual XML data as encoded HTML ... IE:

```
<status>
    <eventData>
        &lt;net id="District 3" name="District 3"&gt;
        &lt;updateTimestamp&gt;2014-04-16T22:15:42-05:00&lt;/updateTimestamp&gt;
        &lt;category&gt;Current&lt;/category&gt;
    </eventData>
</status>
```

So I had no control over how it was being output, and originally I just used basic jQuery via ajax to get the XML, and then with the returned data

```
$.get(eventDataURL, {}, function (rawXML) {
    var xml = $(rawXML).text();
}
```

If I used `$(rawxml).text();` it made it possible to go through each, the problem came when I fed that data to `$(xml).find('event').filter(function(){ ....`

Once it went through `.find` and `.filter` all of the cameCasing was lost, and made a lot of issues for things that relied on camel casing.

So the simple fix was like others mentioned above:

```
$.get(eventDataURL, {}, function (rawXML) {
    var xmlText = $(rawXML).text();
    xml = $.parseXML(xmlText);
}
```

Simply by using `$.parseXML` it converted that text to a valid XML document that didn't lose camelCasing.