# .each() method not working in IE

Tags: jquery, json

**In success method i am unable to loop through xml response.**

**WebMethod is:**

```
Public Shared Function GetTypes(ByVal TypeID As Integer) As String
    Dim db As New DbManager
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    db.AddParameter("@TypeID", TypeID)    
    ds = db.ExecuteDataSet("GetTypes")
    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Types"
    Dim jsSer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Return jsSer.Serialize(ds.GetXml())
End Function
```

**Success Method is**

```
SuccessMethod: function (response, that) {
       $(response).find('Type').each(function (index) {
       alert("called");
})
});
```

**xml response is:**

```
<TypeID>12</TypeID>

<RecordID>5</RecordID>

<CreatedOn>2011-04-24T09:00:00+05:00</CreatedOn>

<Type>Here is type.</Type>
```

```
<TypeID>22</TypeID>

<RecordID>5</RecordID>

<CreatedOn>2011-05-08T09:30:00+05:00</CreatedOn>

<Type>Here is type.</Type>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml response contains "Type", it does not contain "type"...

Comment: above mentioned code working fine in other all browsers except IE. AND I also try with Type. not working

Comment: While XML has case-sensitive element names, [jQuery selectors are still case insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791834/case-insensitivity-in-selectors) so this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using filter() instead. Find generally finds child elements of the selection your using it against.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could also use:

```
$.each($(response).find('Type'), function(index, value) {
  alert('succes');
}
```

Maybe IE is messed up with the difference syntax, this is how jQuery's website describes the function. Although my first guess would be your method aswel..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in IE:

```
response = '<root>' + response + '</root>';
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response);
$(xmlDoc).find('Type').each(function (index,val) {
   alert("called");
});
```

and incidentally, jQUery *is* case-sensitive when parsing XML, so selector must be 'Type', not 'type'. I had to enclose the response given in the question inside a root element to make it valid xml. It could be any unique tag, not necessarily `<root>`

Comment: What version of jQuery & IE are you using? My test file has `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'>` (which is the latest jQuery hosted by google) in the `<head>` section and it works in IE7 & IE8.

Comment: Well, this is puzzling. Have you tried validating the xml? Here's a link for doing so: http://www.stg.brown.edu/pub/xmlvalid/

Comment: one more thing comes to mind. If your jQuery ajax request specifies an xml response, then the server needs to return a text/html content-type header.