# Jquery xml for each loop not working in IE6

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

Slight nightmare. This works in every browser except IE in compatibility mode and IE6.

I've searched and searched and have no clue to why, can anyone shed any light?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Maps/MapResults.aspx",
        dataType: "XML",
        success: function (asd) {

            //This works!
            alert(asd);


            //This doesn't! (in old IE)
            $(asd).find("article").each(function () {

                var category = $(this).find('category').text();
                alert(category);

            });

        }
    }); //close $.ajax(

});
```

Comment: see if this thread helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960740/each-method-not-working-in-ie

Comment: I feel for you, having to support IE6. :-(  If at all possible, drop support for it; it'll save your sanity.

Answer (score 1):

Let MapResults.aspx send and XML-Content-Type-Header (e.g. **application/xml**) .
Also use lowercase-dataType "xml", it may depend on jQuery-Version if dataType is case-sensitive(I'm not 100% sure, but i think it was case-sensitive before 1.5)