# XML parsing in JQuery - how do I get tagName to be the original case of the raw XML?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery converting XML tags to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351527/jquery-converting-xml-tags-to-uppercase)

I am parsing an xml file that is used as a layout for an Android activity.

(Sample)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dashboard_scores" />
```

Here is a sample script for parsing this XML, and finding all elements with the android:id attribute set.

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$xml = $( xmlDoc );
$(xml).find("[android\\:id]").each(function() {
    console.log(this.tagName +" with id "+$(this).attr("android:id"));
}
```

If I print out the value of .tagName, it always prints out in all uppercase.  How do I get it to print out using the original case of the raw XML string?  (Which in this case would be "LinearLayout")

Comment: That's a known problem of jQuery's xml handler, too much like HTML (which is case insensitive). I linked to a question with some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a JQuery limitation.  See ticket here:  http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1991