# How do I perform a case insensitive search for a node in PHP xpath?

Tags: php, xpath

I don't want a search for the string value to be case insensitive. I want to do a search for the node without regard for case sensitivity. If the XML looks like this:

```
<items>
   <ITEM>My text!</ITEM>
</items>
```

I need something like this to work:

```
$someXmlDoc->xpath("/items/item/text()");
```

Currently, only this works:

```
$someXmlDoc->xpath("/items/ITEM/text()");
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625986/how-can-i-use-xpath-to-perform-a-case-insensitive-search-and-support-non-english

The answer is already there :)

Comment: Hi Bjorn -- I did see that, but it looked as if that provided an answer for a case insensitive on a string value, not a node, which is what I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no case conversion in xpath 1.0 as supported by php (see http://jp.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

you *could* use the translate function, shown below in a very limited sense. note: not recommended as it won't work for non-english characters

```
/items/*[translate(node(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'item']/text()
```

Upd:If node() will not work, try name()

you could also do a union as below

```
/items/ITEM/text() | /items/item/text()
```

Comment: The union works, but the translate does not. I am accepting for that answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. XML tags are case-sensitive (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), so `<item>` and `<ITEM>` are two different tags. Thus. `"/items/item/text()"` and `/items/ITEM/text()` are two different paths.

```
<items>
   <ITEM>My text!</ITEM>
   <item>Your text!</item>
</items>
```

"My text" and "Your text" have different `xpath`s

Answer (score 0):

Taking your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948610/how-do-i-parse-xml-from-php-that-was-sent-to-the-server-as-text-xml) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949942/why-when-i-send-xml-to-php-are-the-nodes-lowercase-but-when-i-parse-them-in-php) on the same subject into account another question submerges: "Does it have to be xml?" How about json?
To encode the data as json on the client you can use [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/), which takes only 2kb in the minimized version

```
var jsondata = {
  sender: "CATS",
  subject: "All Your Base",
  items: []
};
for(var i=0; i<8; i++) jsondata.items.push(i);
```

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/test.php",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  data: $.toJSON(jsondata),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
Then your server-side php script can decode the data with [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode), and you will get a native php array/hash according to the json-representation of the javascript object/hash.
For sending data back to the client you can use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode). You get a json representation of your php array and since dataType: "json" was set, jquery will return a native javascript object holding these values/properties.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Fingland first variant did not work for me either,
but I found solution finally.

It should be

```
/items/*[translate(name(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'item']/text()
```